ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.5 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters
This is my code----------------------------------............................
print("shape of waves array",np.array(all_wave).shape)
print("shape of labels array",np.array(all_label).shape)

#Inspecting random sample
time = np.linspace(0, len(samples - 1) / fs, len(samples - 1))
# Assuming that time should have the same length as the first dimension of all_wave
time = np.arange(np.array(all_wave).shape[0])
plt.plot(time,np.array(all_wave)[311:,])
plt.show()

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y=le.fit_transform(all_label)
classes= list(le.classes_)

!pip install scikit-learn
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.src.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=len(labels))

all_wave = np.array(all_wave).reshape(-1,22050,1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(np.array(all_wave),np.array(y), stratify=y,test_size = 0.5,random_state=777,shuffle=True)

Show this problems in the code..................................................
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 2 x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(np.array(all_wave),np.array(y), stratify=y,test_size = 0.5,random_state=777,shuffle=True)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _validate_shuffle_split(n_samples, test_size, train_size, default_test_size)
   2234 
   2235     if n_train == 0:
-> 2236         raise ValueError(
   2237             "With n_samples={}, test_size={} and train_size={}, the "
   2238             "resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the "

ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.5 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.


What's the shape of all_wave? If 22050 is the number of observations, you may want to make that the first dimension of the array.

You don't need to call np.array again every time you use an array.
